# What IP should be specified in lwipcfg_msvc.h?

Tags: c, windows, freertos, lwip

I am trying to set up lwIP simulation on Windows 7.

I have downloaded current version of lwIP and contrib files (v1.4.1), upgraded .sln and .vcproj(s) to MSVC 2013, download WinPcap 4.1.1. I have set up lwipcfg_msvc.h (IP address, MAC address, PACKET_LIB_ADAPTER_NR, LWIP_HTTPD_APP (sample of http server)) and run project lwip_test. But can't see any result in browser. I have also tried set up another IP address than my computer's local address, but with no luck.

Than I tried this project http://interactive.freertos.org/entries/20290712-FreeRTOS-Win32-project-with-lwIP-web-server, which is also not working for me.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY!

IP address must be different from computer's address, but must be from local network address range.
I.e.:

```
my computer settings:
IP: 192.168.0.100
mask: 255.255.255.0
GW: 192.168.0.1

lwip settings (in lwipcfg_msvc.h):
IP: 192.168.0.222
mask: 255.255.255.0
GW: 192.168.0.1
```

MAC address can be whatever.

But that was not the main problem. The key thing was that I had to disable IP, UDP and TCP checksum checking! Simply by adding next three lines at the end of lwipopts.h:

```
#define CHECKSUM_CHECK_IP         0
#define CHECKSUM_CHECK_UDP        0
#define CHECKSUM_CHECK_TCP        0
```

Comment: In the Windows port, LwIP is using WinPcap to inject and receive packets on the configured network interface inside the kernel. As you've identified, to communicate with the Windows IP stack also running on the same interface, the LwIP interface needs to be on the same subnet, but have a different IP address (it's another network stack/software device)